# Convert Apple II 'action' format to PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion

I just downloaded my Social Security Benefit letter for year 2020 in preparation for filing my 2020 US Income Tax.

In years past, this document has been in PDF format. And the SS website claims that the document is in PDF format. But, actually, it is the mothballed Apple II .action format.

I am having difficulty finding any useful information online on how to do the conversion on a linux system.

How can I convert from file.action to file.pdf on a Ubuntu? [ubuntu 20.10 in my case]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution.

Since the Social Security Administration chose to use this ancient format, others will likely encounter the same problem this year.

So I am posting this just in case others need the information.

The .action file format can be opened in LibreOffice Draw.

In my case, the document was cluttered with spurious text boxes, but I was able to select and delete them resulting in a fairly clean document which can be saved in PDF format.